# How is each situation similar to tossing a coin.

Tags: probability

besides there being a 50% probability of each occurring?

A. Predicting the sex of an unborn child
B. Guessing the answer to a true-false question 
C. Picking the winner if a two-team game
D. Picking the winner of a two-person election

Comment: I'm not sure if each has a $50/50$ outcome. For instance it is not clear a priori that men/women are born with equal probability. The only one that does for sure is $B$.

Comment: In fact the probability of a boy-birth is around $0.51$, not much larger than $0.5$, but significant larger. Concerning $C$ : If you choose the winner of a soccer match with teams of very different playing strength, the probability to pick the winner will not be $0.5$. A similar argument holds for $D$.

Comment: @Peter (Unless, of course, you are picking the winner by flipping a coin $\ddot\smile$)

Answer (score 2):

These are all binary random variables.